# Using object properties that aren't listed in Object Browser

Tags: vba, excel, object, methods

I've been looking into the underlying structure of object properties and methods in VBA a bit more. I've just read that all properties and methods for each object is listed in the "Object Browser" in the developer box.

The reason why I was prompted to look at this was that I used a method that wasn't listed in the Object Browser. I used:

```
Sheets("Front face").Shapes("Drop Down 12").ControlFormat
```

This allowed me to then use .List to change the Shape. However .ControlFormat isn't a property/method listed in Object Browser.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: FYI, you may want to look into the worksheet's `Dropdowns` collection - that *isn't* shown in the Object Browser by default; you have to right-click and choose to show hidden members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

It appears in mine - perhaps you're looking for "Shapes" which is a collection, as opposed to "Shape" which is the actual object?

---

***Detail:***

`Shapes` is a *collection* of `Shape` objects - therefore `Shapes` has properties and methods that relate to a `Collection` object. Each item in that collection is a `Shape` object which has the properties and methods of a `Shape`

Comment: Thanks Macro Man! Yes, I was looking at Shapes not Shape. Seems like I now need to look into collection objects and then which objects are collection objects and which aren't...

Comment: Generally speaking, anything _plural_ is a `collection` of the _singular_ version. `Workbooks()`, `Worksheets()` (aka `Sheets()`), `Shapes()` are a collection of `Workbook`, `Worksheet` and `Shape` objects respectively.

Answer (score 5):

Besides what MacroMan explained, here is something you should always follow (as a habit)

**Work with objects for intellisense to work correctly**.

See this Example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Shp As Shape

    Set ws = Sheets("Front face")
    Set Shp = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 12")
End Sub
```

Now if you do `Shp.` you will get the `.ControlFormat` property.

Another example

When you want to access the `.Range` of a worksheet, you will not get that if you type `Activesheet.`. For intellisense, again work with objects.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if/when the Warlords of Documentation comes about an article on Objects/IntelliSense/Early Binding would save a lot of people a lot of time!

Comment: Just came across this comment again, and then had a little laugh to myself about documentation... \*chuckle\*