# Get name of selected grouped Shapes

Tags: vba, excel

I created two oval shape objects which are named by default as "Oval 1" and "Oval 2". I grouped both of them and named it "MergedOvals". I assigned a macro to the newly formed group shape.

The macro has code that gives the name of the shape object when I click it:

```
Sub ClickedShape()
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name & " Clicked"
End Sub
```

The problem is, when I click the grouped shapes, I am expecting the MsgBox to show "MergedOvals Clicked", but instead, the original "Oval 1" or "Oval 2" names are shown depending on the proximity of the cursor to the ovals.

Is there a way that it should show the grouped name?

Comment: proram code by @Siddharth Rout works fine for me. Are you still having problem. In that case I may send you my sample sheet.

Comment: The code of Siddharth Rout is perfect for my need. Still appreciate your offer to help skkakkar.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582677/using-object-properties-that-arent-listed-in-object-browser/32583577#32583577), work with objects so that you can access the intellisense. That way you can discover what all `Object Properties` you have at your disposal.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub ClickedShape()
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    MsgBox shp.ParentGroup.Name & " Clicked"
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code performed exactly what i was trying to do. Thank you.